# Access Google cloud SQL instance from Google cloud function using a service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to access Google cloud SQL instance from Google cloud function using a service account without coding database username and password on cloud function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage Cloud SQL using service account credentials. You cannot login and authenticate to the database (MySQL / PostreSQL) using a service account. You must use username and password.

Google Cloud SQL is a managed database service. This means all the infrastructure required to run MySQL or PostreSQL in the cloud plus management. To login to the database software itself that runs inside Cloud SQL, you must use the authentication method that the database requires. This is username and password.